# Center a subview horizontally with custom vertical distance | Swift

Tags: swift

I have the following subview that I would like to centered in horizontally on the screen and set the vertical distance manually.

```
    let customImageView = AnimationView(name: "image")
    customImageView.frame = CGRect(x: -140, y: 40, width: 700, height: 700)
    customImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    self.view.addSubview(customImageView)
```

Is it possible to ensure that the vertical distance set will account if the screen size of the phone is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for Auto Layout (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html), which is Apple's constraint-based system made specifically to dynamically size views in relation to other views and screen sizes. In your case, you could set a greater than/less than to constraint to the top of the view and your subview, so that it will be at least a certain amount of spacing with the option to grow if the screen is larger/smaller.

If you would like to still do frame based layouts (e.g. creating a CGRect/frame), you'll have to do the math yourself based on the view.frame.size.height value. Be aware that a view controller's view frame might not be set before `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called.